# Magento 2 : Admin Grid Pagination Issue

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent, pagination

In magento admin, custom grid pagination is not working. I have 3 records in database, When I enter 2 records/page then next page button remains disabled and it will not show remaining 1 record.

This is Default setting when page is loaded.
[image]

This is the actual issue.
[image]

As soon as i type 2 and press enter it shows correct values until the grid is loading as in below image.But when grid loaded it will not show remaining record.
[image]

Below is the code of grid xml before columns

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">productattachments_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New File</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="productattachments_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ProductattachmentsGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">productattachments_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.productattachments_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.productattachments_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.productattachments_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <filterSelect name="store_id">
            <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</argument>
            </argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                    <item name="captionValue" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSelect>
    </filters>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.productattachments_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">productattachments_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="productattachmentsadmin/productattachments/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="disable">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="productattachmentsadmin/productattachments/massDisable"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="enable">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="productattachmentsadmin/productattachments/massEnable"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="edit">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.productattachments_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing.productattachments_listing.productattachments_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
```

Comment: check the network tab from browser is there any error coming.

Comment: no error in network tab. i have also checked grid code line by line and cant find any issue.

Comment: there is another issue when i change records/page to previous one then grid is filled with all dublicate values.

Comment: did u added grid collection model?

Comment: yes i have added grid collection model. I have edit my question and add 3rd screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in grid collection file.
After implementing all SearchResultInterface methods the issue was gone.

Answer (score 1):

In the:

```
<dataSource name="productattachments_listing_data_source">
```

You should add these lines to dataProvider:

```
<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">YOUR_INDEX_FIELD</item>
</item>
```

So in a result it will look like this:

```
<dataSource name="productattachments_listing_data_source">
<argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ProductattachmentsGridDataProvider</argument>
    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">productattachments_listing_data_source</argument>
    <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">productattachments_id</argument>
    <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string"> productattachments_id</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</argument>
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
    </item>
</argument>
</dataSource>
```

Also, you forget to close "listing" tag

Comment: The issue was in model/ResourceModel/Modulename/Grid/Collection.php

Comment: good answer thank you helped me out